# C++ dangling reference to Eigen::Matrix created in function

Tags: c++, eigen

Would the following example create a dangling reference? (Since the `vector<int>` is local in the function and the `MatrixXi` is using a reference to this data). Also considering the Foo constructor takes a reference to the `MatrixXi`.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Core>
using Eigen::MatrixXi;

static Eigen::MatrixXi CreateMatrix()
{
    std::vector<int> data(4);
    data = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    Eigen::MatrixXi mat = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>(&data[0], 2, 2);
    return mat;
}

class Foo
{
public:
    const MatrixXi matrix;
    Foo(const MatrixXi &matrix) : matrix(matrix) {}
    void Bar() {
        std::cout << matrix << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo test(CreateMatrix());
    test.Bar();

    Foo* test2 = new Foo(CreateMatrix());
    test2->Bar();

    std::cin.get();

    delete test2;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Added the `delete test2` to free the memory.

**EDIT2:**

The actual creation of the MatrixXi in the real problem is based on a parameter of the function and looks like this (C++/CLI):

```cpp
static Eigen::MatrixXi CreateMatrix(MathNet::Numerics::LinearAlgebra::Matrix<float>^ data)
{
    int length = data->RowCount * data->ColumnCount;
    std::vector<int> data_out(length);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < data->RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < data->ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            data_out[i * data->ColumnCount + j] = data[i, j];
        }
    }

    Eigen::MatrixXi mat = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>(&data_out[0], data->RowCount, data->ColumnCount);

    return mat;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To prove the answer from davidhigh is correct I've written the following test:

```cpp
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto map = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>(&data[0], 2, 2);
    Eigen::MatrixXi mat = map;
    data[0] = 5;
    std::cout << "mat:\n" << mat << std::endl;
    std::cout << "map:\n" << map << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

This gives console output:

```
mat:
1 2
3 4
map:
5 2
3 4
```

So no dangling reference since mat is no longer connected to data (while map is).

Comment: You are doing a lot of useless copying and you don't free/destruct `test2` at the end, but there is no dangling reference.

Comment: Sorry, correcting myself: you return the `MatrixXi` and not the `Map`... this is correct. Returning just the `Map` object would be a dangling reference, however.

Comment: How would I avoid the useless copying?

Comment: Why would returning the `Map` result in a dingling reference, but returning the `MatrixXi` not?

Comment: If you return only the map and use it outside, it wants to access the vector which is has already been destructed on exit of the function CreateMatrix. However, you store the map inside a MatrixXi which owns the data it refers to, so this will work. What people mean by "useless copy" is, that you then could also directly create the matrix and fill it. But maybe your real problem is more complicated (you could get the vector from an external library, say), then I would n't call it a useless copy (than it's rather a necessary one).

Comment: You are right, the actual problem is more complicated. I've edited my question to show the more complicated problem.

Comment: But also for the updated problem, there is no need for Eigen::Map. Just create a MatrixXd -- note the Xd, it should not be Xi as you want a floating point matrix -- and fill it with two simple for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as the status of this thread became a bit confusing, I'll add another answer and detail what I already wrote in the comments.

- It is ok to return a `MatrixXi` inside the function `CreateMatrix` and return it. You perform the creation of the matrix via copying from an `Eigen::Map`, which is also ok.
- In your simple example, you could get around the `Map` by directly initializing the `MatrixXi`, e.g. via `operator<<`. In more general scenarios, maybe all you got is a vector, and then your approach is again ok.
- It's crucial that you return the `MatrixXi` here. If you would return the `Map` object, this will -- in general -- lead to a dangling reference. Then, for example, if you call `operator()` outside, the `Map` wants to access the vector which is already destructed at exit of `CreateMatrix()`. (Actually, in your special example, it would work, as you directly use the result to create a `Foo`, which is again storing the `Map` inside a matrix -- still, it's not a good idea to write a function that's so error prone).
- Final point: don't do this raw pointer stuff with `test2` which you did in your main function. There's absolutely no use for it here. Use RAII, which is basically your first approach in main.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. For similar problems, how would I find out that the `MatrixXi` object is owning the data, but the `Map` object is not? Is there any way to write a test for that?

Comment: First, I would read the docs, thereafter check the code (if that's possible). If that does not bring the desired result, it's your turn to keep the referenced object alive, e.g. by writing a wrapper around Map that also contains the vector by value.

Answer (score 0):

Your mat returned from the CreateMatrix() call is holding the address of a temporary std::vector which is out of scope outside that function. 
There is no guarantee that address will still be holding what you want. 
You need to make the std::vector more permanent. It has to exist outside of CreateMatrix() or you will be in trouble.